# Looping through a 2D array?

Tags: swift

This might be a noob question, but I'm trying to loop through this 2D array and change every element of the 2D array into a 1 except for the last column at 10, and yes I want it in string form. Any Ideas?

```
var excelArray = [[String]](repeating: [String](repeating: "N/A", count: 10), count: 27)
```

Comment: Please add your attempt at solving this and also a sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply change all the array to 1 and them reset the last column into "N/A"

```swift
var excelArray = [[String]](repeating: [String](repeating: "1", count: 10), count: 27)

for i in 0..<27 {
    excelArray[i][9] = "N/A"
}

print(excelArray)
```